# I can't customize summary reports

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to add a column with the response Body present in the Results tree view to the summary report?

I would like to generate a simple report with Jmeter that contains Average, Label, Error taken from the summary report and in case of error it must insert the complete exception in the csv so that it can be imported into an .xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) storing response data in CSV format is not supported.

[image]

So you won't be able to have a "column".

You will either need to switch JMeter's [.jtl result file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) to use XML format output and configure JMeter to save response data along with your other metrics or add a listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) or [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) and store what you need into a separate XML file.

The XML files can be ingested into Excel via [Import XML data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-xml-data-6eca3906-d6c9-4f0d-b911-c736da817fa4) functionality

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter)